# Aquamacs initialization for CIDER

Tags: aquamacs, cider

I've tried putting the following in my Preferences.el file:

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'cider-turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq cider-prompt-save-file-on-load nil)
```

Unfortunately, this has no effect.  Is there something more I need to do to get these to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following at the top should do the trick:

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'cider-mode)
```

`cider-mode` does not load by default for `clojure-mode` files.